# What parts of Bitcoin's Lightning Network can be ported to Monero?

Tags: bitcoin, lightning-network

As a fork of Bytecoin, Monero has been unable to directly port much of the tools and code written for Bitcoin and its forks. However, as a layer-2 solution, what parts of Lightning would need to be rewritten for Monero? Would the [Lightning Network Daemon](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd) be compatible with minimal changes, for instance? What are some things that wouldn't be compatible?

Thanks

Comment: Monero fortunately doesn't suffer the same scalability problem Bitcoin has.Thus, to what purpose would porting LN to Monero hold?

Comment: I've removed the scaling tag. I'm more interested in the future of LN regarding other advantages like cross-chain swaps, messaging services, etc/ that are easier developed on second layer than main chain.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Network (LN) was predominantly devised as a way to scale Bitcoin (in terms of both throughput and keeping tx costs low). Some people also throw in "privacy", but that has been largely debunked, e.g. <sup>[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.00333v1.pdf)</sup>.

Monero doesn't have these problems, hence there is not some great need for LN with Monero.

Another much trumpeted "feature" of LN is the potential for cross-chain atomic swaps. However, this has also come up against some criticism, for example <sup>[2](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/2018-December/001752.html)</sup>.

Leaving aside the questionable needs / benefits of LN, the question isn't really what or not can be "ported" due to the fact Monero is not a Bitcoin clone, but rather: is it *possible* to implement LN for Monero. And the answer to this right now is no. LN requires time-lock and refund mechanisms to operate. Whilst some kind of time-lock trickery could perhaps be achieved, due to the way the blockchain and transactions operate, there is no refund mechanism currently.

So,

> ... what parts of Lightning would need to be rewritten for Monero?

Monero would need non-trivial changes to be able to use the LN scheme. Then any LN daemon would need work to implement on top of the Monero blockchain. Thus "what parts" is actually a lot of *both*.

> Would the Lightning Network Daemon be compatible with minimal changes, for instance?

No.

> What are some things that wouldn't be compatible?

Given how tightly any 2nd layer needs to operate with any base layer, there's a considerable amount of incompatibility.

Lastly,

> Monero has been unable to directly port much of the tools and code written for Bitcoin and its forks

You say this like it's some kind of negative. There are *many* issues with Bitcoin's (and its forks) design and code. Monero is not a fork of Bitcoin for good reason.